# How to convert property from one type to another?

Tags: c#, .net, type-conversion

In my code I get the type of a property using reflection like this:

```
 foreach(FilterRule rule in filter.Rules)
 {
     PropertyInfo property = typeof(T).GetProperty(rule.Field);
 }
```

After that I make several checks to find out what type is it actually and if the type is `long?` :

```
 else if (property.PropertyType == typeof(long?))
 {
     long dd = Convert.ChangeType(rule.Field, System.Int64);
 }
```

I want to convert to `System.Int64` type. Or be more specific to just `long` without nullable but it seems that I'm not getting this because `rule.Field` is `String` and it says that the first argument should be an `object` and I see there are some overlords but there's none that uses the syntax that I'm trying.

How can I do this conversion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your usage of `Convert.ChangeType`, the second parameter should be `typeof(System.Int64)` (the `typeof` operator returns an instance of `System.Type`) rather than simply `System.Int64`.

Also, you should add an explicit cast to `long` (since `ChangeType` returns an `Object`):

```
long dd = (long)Convert.ChangeType(rule.Field, typeof(System.Int64));
```

However, this seems to be a perfect case to use the [`Convert.ToInt64` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.convert.toint64.aspx) instead:

```
long dd = Convert.ToInt64(rule.Field);
```

Answer (score 1):

How about using **[Convert.ToInt64()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.convert.toint64.aspx)** method?

> Converts a specified value to a 64-bit signed integer.

```
long lfield = Convert.ToInt64(rule.Field);
```

as

```
var lfield = (long)Convert.ChangeType(rule.Field, typeof(System.Int64));
```

Since **[this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ttf5d382.aspx)** overload of `Convert.ChangeType` returns an `object`, you can cast it to `long` value.